# Observer - Stop controller action after review_save_after

Tags: magento-1.7, frontend, event-observer, review

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2. I need to prevent ratings in the frontend from saving after the reviews has been saved. So I have used the `<reveiw_save_after>` event in order to achieve it. But I am unable to stop the controller action from happening after the save event. Here is my code:

`etc\config.xml`

```
    <events>
        <review_save_after>
            <observers>
                <rating_prevent_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MyModule_Rating_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>preventAddRatings</method>
                </rating_prevent_observer>
            </observers>
        </review_save_after>
    </events>
```

`Rating\Model\Observer.php`

```
     class MyModule_Rating_Model_Observer
     {
        function preventAddRatings(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            $app = Mage::app();
            $request = $app->getRequest();

$app->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($request->getBaseUrl() . $request->getPathInfo());
        }
    }
```

The observer is calling but the controller action is still executing. Is this the correct way to prevent the controller action?.

Thanks.

**Update:**

I tried using the below code but I am unable to get the controller action from the observer object.

`$controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
$controller->getRequest()->setDispatched(true);
$controller->setFlag(
    '', 
    Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, 
    true
);`

Answer (score 2):

After setting the redirect you need to call the response object's `sendResponse()` method and terminate execution.

Note that your observer needs to be configured under the `frontend` event area, as it would not be appropriate for this redirect to occur in the admin.

Comment: I added the observer in the `<frontend>` tag and the code is calling after the review save event, but I tried adding the `$request->sendResponse()` after the `setRedirect()` which you mentioned, but no luck, the rest of the controller code gets executed. I tried putting `exit()`, the reviews are not saving.

Comment: In most cases `return;` is good enough. Don't call exit or die - makes testing difficult.

Comment: `return` will not work in this case, because the remaining execution scope may set a *different* redirect header on the response object before it is sent by the Front Controller.